# Odd performance of jQuery variable caching and chaining

Tags: jquery, performance, chain

I've read everywhere that variable caching and chaining jQuery function calls was good for performance.

However, I've come across [this jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/caching-jquery-objects-perf/13) that seems to demonstrate some interesting quirks.

Please see the below test cases:

**Case 1: No Caching**

```
$(".myClass").css("color", "red");
$(".myClass").css("opacity", 1);
$(".myClass").css("display", "block");
```

**Case 2: Chaining**

```
$(".myClass").css("color", "red").css("opacity", 1).css("display", "block");
```

**Case 3: Object Caching**

```
var $myDiv = $(".myDiv");
$myDiv.css("color", "red");
$myDiv.css("opacity", 1);
$myDiv.css("display", "block");
```

**Case 4: Object Caching + Chaining**

```
var $myDiv = $(".myClass");
$myDiv.css("color", "red").css("opacity", 1).css("display", "block");
```

**Case 5: normal jQuery**

```
$(".myClass").css({
  color: "red",
  opacity: 1,
  display: "block"
});
```

Here's the performance test results on my computer (Win7 FF18) ordered by test cases:

1. **No Caching - 7,284 ops/s - 92% slower, slowest**
2. Chaining - 10,284 ops/s - 89% slower
3. **Object Caching - 95,968 ops/s - fastest**
4. Object Caching + Chaining - 10,353 ops/s - 89% slower
5. Normal jQuery - 10,172 ops/s - 89% slower

*(These results are conform with measurements made with other browsers.)*

As you can see, the test case 1 is the slowest which was expected.
Oddly, the test case 3 is the fastest, while the test case 2, 4 and 5 are quite slow too.

The biggest surprise is that the test case 3 is much faster than test case 4. In other words, chaining jQuery calls greatly reduced performance.

Have you noticed this on your own browser?

Maybe it's a perk of the .css() method, but personally, I think that modern Javascript engines have already made special code optimisations to enhance sequences of function calls from the same root object.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Object Caching" test is so much faster because it's not actually doing anything.

It uses a different selector than the others: `.myDiv` instead of `.myClass`. There are no `.myDiv` elements, so the calls are acting on an empty result set.

If you [fix that broken test](http://jsperf.com/caching-jquery-objects-perf/16), you get results more like what you'd expect: repeating the selector is still slowest, and the other 4 options are all more or less equivalent, speed-wise.

Comment: Doh `myDiv`... Thumbs up for the quick response!